# How can i make a color opacity in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have this site:

http://avocat.dac-proiect.ro/wp/?page_id=10

Currently there you put the arrow over the image hover effect.

```
    .container_sus img:hover{
    opacity:0.5;
}

.container_jos img:hover{
    opacity:0.5;
}
```

Opacity is gray ... I want to be a blue haze.

I have attached a picture to better understand how they want to do.

http://i59.tinypic.com/j7t2e8.png

How can I solve this problem?

Can you help me please?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now it's showing you the white of the background of the page.  You need a background color of the full opacity of the blue you want.  Then you add that to the parent li tag like so:

```
.lista_sus li {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
margin: 0px 9px 5px 0px;
background-color: #041067;  /* this is just a sample - the color you put here would be the full opacity blue you want */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
        *{
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        body{
            margin: auto;
        }
        .container{
            width: 100%;
            height: 500px;
            background: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/206959/pexels-photo-206959.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500);
            background-size: cover;
            background-position: center;
            display: flex;

        }
        .container:before{
            content: "";
            background: #e2c336;
            width: 100%;
            opacity: 0.5;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this css to your stylesheet:

```
.lista_sus li {
    background: #674172;
}
```